# nginx configuration for / only

Tags: nginx, webserver

This is my current configuration in nginx: (folder1 2 3 4 are just shortcuts for the example here)

```
location /folder1 { include localfolder.conf; } 
location /folder2 { include localfolder.conf; }
location /folder3 { include localfolder.conf; }
location /folder4 { include localfolder.conf; }
location / { proxy_pass http://192.168.0.250/; }
```

You can see I redirect all calls to another second webserver except for /folder1 2 3 and 4.
When I just call /, it also redirects to the second webserver. This works great so far when the second webserver is running.

My problem is, nginx should deliver its local documents (/usr/share/nginx/www) only for / when the second webserver is not running.

I read the docs but I have no Idea how to achieve that...

Thank you for your ideas and help.

EDIT:

I added the following line to the configuration inside the "location /" brackets:

```
error_page 502 = http://ANYDOMAIN/;
```

Now the redirect works if the server is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the  [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream):

```
upstream fishing {
    server 192.168.0.250;     # try this one first
    server localhost backup;  # use this if the above does not respond
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fishing;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it's something to explore.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it did not work as expected. I still got a "Bad Request" when I used this. I even tried using the local IP-address insted of localhost, but no luck.